# Where do I call the "payment was successful" message from?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe into my site. The code below is copied directly from stripe's documentation. Although there are minor differences between this code and my implementation, such differences are not relevant to the question as both my code and the code is shown work correctly

First I install relevant files.

> composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "stripe/stripe-php": "*"
    }
}
```

Then I make a checkout in JavaScript. (This one charges $9.99 for "Example Charge" but you get the idea. Below is a simple checkout, mine is a custom checkout, but that should not make a difference to the question.)

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="<test key here>"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="<myName>"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-currency="aud">
  </script>
</form>
```

This checkout is pretty good at catching *most* errors, and if it can't find any, it passes a token on for me to charge.

Finally, I added a page to create the charge

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("<test key here>");
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'aud',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
]);
```

So far it is good. In the testing environment, this always succeeds. Or, if I test a card that should not succeed, it always fails at the checkout.

However, suppose the token is created successfully, but then the issue happens server side. **How do I detect that?**

More specifically, if I were to have a function like `alert("Your payment has been successful")` or `echo "Your payment has been successful"`, **Where would be the correct place to call that from?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out shortly after posting.

First I noticed that `$charge` is an output in this context, so I ran `echo var_dump($charge);` which opened up a massive wealth of information.

Rather than look at it there, I can find the api reference [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges), scroll down to "The Charge Object". Within that, `status` (relating to `$charge['status']`) can confirm if it was successful or not.

The working code `if($charge['status'] === "succeeded"){}` is the correct place to put a success message.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("<test key here>");
  $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'aud',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
  ]); 

  if(isset($charge->id) && $charge->id != ''){
  echo "Payment has been made successful, Transaction ID : ".$charge->id;exit;
  }
} catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
  echo "Something went wrong with payment, Note : ".$e->getMessage();exit;

}
```

Comment: Down voters should at least comment here with valid reason!